# Multiple plots in Shiny dynamic UI

Tags: r, plot, dynamic, shiny

I am trying to dynamically insert a number of plots in a shiny app. I have reduced this to a simple example which displays three histograms with the same number of bins (48), even though they should be different (16, 32, 48). Possibly I've done something really stupid, or am missing something more subtle! Code is attached. Thanks in advance for any suggetions.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(tagList(
          actionButton("button_id", "Show plot"),
          uiOutput("plot_id"),
          HTML("<div id=\"end\">The end</div>"))))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # A list to hold the plot IDs
ls <- list()

observeEvent(input$button_id,
{
    x <- faithful[, 2]

    for (i in 1:3)
    {
            # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        count <- i * 16
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = count)

        ls[[i]] <<- paste0("plot_", i)

        output[[ls[[i]]]] <- renderPlot(hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white'))
    }
    output$plot_id <- renderUI({


        wellPanel(do.call(tagList, lapply(ls, function(x) 
        { 
            plotOutput(x) 
        })))

    })

})

})
```

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the lazy evaluation that causes the problem here. The code for the histogram is not executed immediately, but only when the plot is going to be rendered. This is after the `for`-loop has completed and `i` has the value 3.

In order to force instant evaluation, you can wrap the body of your loop in a `local` environment like this:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    local({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    count <- i * 16
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = count)

    ls[[i]] <<- paste0("plot_", i)
    output[[ls[[i]]]] <- renderPlot(hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white'))
    })
}
```